# How to count the elements of order 196 in a given abelian group

Tags: group-theory

The abelian group $A_2$ is defined as $C_4 \times C_4 \times C_{49} \times C_7$ and I need to find the number of elements of order $196$ in $A_2$.

I understand that I must take an element of order $49$ from $C_{49}$

My notes say that $C_7$ can be arbitary but I don't completely understand why this is.

I don't really understand what to do with the $C_4$ components.

Please help me to understand a method to find the number of elements of order $196$.

Comment: You "must let" $\;C_{49}\;$ be of order $\;49\;$" ?? Aren't all those cyclic groups: $\;C_n\;$ the cyclic group of order $\;n\;$ ?

Comment: I don't understand what "C7 can be arbitrary" means!

Comment: You should really improve this question so that the question appears in the text as well as the title and so that it is in clear sentences rather than notes. I will make a start with some editing, but you should check that it is still the question you want to ask.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mbox{o}(x)$ be the order of element $x$ in its group.

For $(a,b,c,d)$ to be of order $196$, you need $\mbox{lcm}(\mbox{o}(a),\mbox{o}(b),\mbox{o}(c),\mbox{o}(d))=196$

$o(a)$ is $1, 2,$ or $4$;

$o(b)$ is $1, 2,$ or $4$;

$o(c)$ is $1, 7,$ or $49$;

$o(d)$ is $1$ or $7$.

To get the least common multiple to work out right, you need at least one of $a$ or $b$ to have order $4$, and $c$ to have order $49$.  Once you have these conditions met, the order of $d$ can be either $1$ or $7$.

Answer (score 3):

Notice that $196=4\times 49$

Your group $A_2$ is abelian, so to get the order $196$ you need to combine an element of order $4$ from the $C_4 \times C_4$ part of the group with an element of order $49$ from the $C_{49}\times C_7$ part of the group.

$C_4\times C_4$ has sixteen elements, and these elements will have order $4$ unless they combine an element of order $1$ or $2$ in the first component with an element of order $1$ or $2$ in the second component. There are two elements of order $1$ or $2$ in each component, so $2\times 2=4$ in the product, leaving $12$ elements of order $4$. You will want to check where these numbers come from, and that they are correct.

Elements of $C_{49}\times C_7$ have order $49$ only if they involve an element of order $49$ from the first component. The second component contributes nothing because all its elements have order $1$ or $7$ and these are both factors of $49$ - so we can take any element we like from the second component (hence 'arbitrary'), provided we have an element of order $49$ from the first. You will want to check that this gives $42\times 7$ possibilities, and then combine the two results to get your answer.