# Finding the number of elements of a specific order in a group

Tags: group-theory

I'm asked to find the number of elements of order $24$ in $C_8 \times C_8 \times C_3 \times C_5$. From the solutions, I can sort of see how to do this. However, on a similar question I'm asked to find the number of elements of order $196$ in $C_4 \times C_4 \times C_{49} \times C_7$, and the method doesn't look the same. We never really went over this in lectures but it's in all the exam papers, what is the general method to solve these?

Comment: Hi @Jam, it is always a good idea tell us what have you tried so far.

Comment: Note the $C_24$ and $C_196$ are subgroups of the two groups respectively.

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is that the order of an element $(w,x,y,z)$ in the group $C_{n_1}\times C_{n_2}\times C_{n_3}\times C_{n_4}$ with coprime $n_i$ is the least common multiple of the orders of $w$,$x$,$y$ and $z$ in the corresponding cyclic group $C_{n_i}$. This reduces the question to the number of elements of order $d$ in a cyclic group $C_n$. Now the number of elements of order $d$, where $d$ is a divisor of $n$, is $\varphi(d)$. There are many examples given on MSE (including what to do for prime powers) see for example [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1089503/how-to-count-the-elements-of-order-196-in-a-given-abelian-group?rq=1), concerning the number of elements of order $196$ in $C_4 \times C_4 \times C_{49} \times C_7$.